# Get name of XmlElementAttribute after deserialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I haven't found any information on this, maybe someone could help.

I have an XML (simplified for convenience):

```
<content>
  <field1>value</field1>
  <field2>
    <field3>value</field3>
  </field2>
</content>
```

I try to deserialize it using such classes:

```
[XmlRoot("content")]
public class Content
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Item> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{

    [XmlElement]
    public List<Item> Fields { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Can I get the actual name of the field? Like `[XmlName] string name;` in the Item class? Or some kind of an attribute for the class itself? It is not possible to set the node name to "field" and add "type" attribute, for some reasons ;-) While the actual class and serialization process is really complicated, I'd prefer not to implement my own serializer.
2. Can I add a wildcard like [XmlElement("field*")]? I can't test it until I know the answer to the first question, so if there is a better option, I'd love to know it as well.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a structure that can represent arbitrary XML. If that's the case, why are you using XML serialization at all? Using LINQ to XML might be a better fit.

Comment: Well, you're right, it is quite an arbitrary structure. The point is, that I have already used XML serialization in many cases, I wanted to keep this convention in my whole project (it was possible, until now...). Of course, if I won't find the solution, I'll switch to LINQ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer here is that it's, unfortunately, not possible.

As a result we have written our own serialization routine.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the name of the matching XMl- Element or Attribute in the Constructor of the Attribute

```
[XmlAttribute("FieldAsAttribute")]
```

--> Will Serialize / Deserialize the Property to the Xml Attribute *FieldAsAttribute*
or

```
[XmlElement("FieldAsElement")]
```

--> Will Serialize / Deserialize the Property to the Xml Element *FieldAsElement*

Comment: It would serialize/deserialize only elements with such names. I need, as @svick mentioned above, to deserialize arbitrary XML structure.